# When will my reflection show, who I am inside

Tags: society

Set in the present day, all of a sudden we can no longer see our reflection clearly. Remember when you took a train or cab and then everything moving in the opposite direction seems to blur, our eyes are incapable of resolving huge amount of details especially when moving therefore the brain will have to compensate by filling in the missing information causing us to see motion blur. Now whenever we try to peek at our own reflection either through a mirror or with image/video recording all we see is blur, however we can still see each other perfectly even indirectly.

Assume we can still remember how we use to look like except for those who is less privilege, I know the beauty industry will fold up anyway my question is will the society be forgiving and remains as it is or breaks apart due to some psychological reasons?

Comment below should there be any doubt.

Comment: Everyone is blurred when appears on mirror or on film, right, not only yourself I hope? What about drawings?

Comment: Twins must be so confused.

Comment: So many shaving cuts.

Comment: Even the beauty industry would be fine. Make-up would probably be worn only on occasions, but the rest of industry (skin care, haircuts, diets, clothes, accessories, whatever) would live on.

Comment: @Roux Might do better - instead of applying makeup yourself, you'd probably have to have someone do it for you. But I don't really specialize in these topics...

Comment: I am kind of curious how this might happen. As it stands, I don't know that I could fully answer. For example, if I video someone, is their picture stored right? Does this process happen on the capture end (ie, the light reflecting, being picked up by the sensor, etc.) or on the viewing end (in the person's own eyes/brain)? If magic is the answer I can understand not having a solution to this, but if there's some technical reason, it's an angle that is worth addressing.

Comment: Vampires will just ask what the problem is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say society will be ok. Possibly even better off.

If you go back just a few hundred years, the majority of people probably didn't have access to mirrors anyway. And if not knowing what exactly you look like would be a unsurmountable psychological problem, blind people would be going mad left, right and centre.

People would still care about their appearance, it would just be more difficult to assess it. I'd guess the first make-up-assessment app would hit the market pretty quickly ...

Still, people would probably be less vain. It's hard to fuss over something you cannot really check firsthand.

Maybe there would be some creative applications of mirrors and pictures. Say, I don't want somebody to be able to use my computer, I could just use a pic of his face as screen background.